# Using loops to copy specific ranges from one workbook to another

Tags: vba, excel

Can you help me solve my VB code problem that would copy named ranges from a specific tab of an excel file (source workbook: worksheet 1) to the same named tab in another excel file (target workbook: worksheet 1)? I need to use a for loop or for each statement for multiple tabs to be copied.  The tabs are numerically named (eg. 1, 2, 4, 7, etc.) and as you can see, it may skip a number so that n = n + 1 may not work. Also, depending on the user input for a given period (eg. 1Q2013, 2Q2013, 3Q2013, 4Q2013), the named range or range data to be copied from and to will vary.

Any efficiency you can add as well is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!
Ann

```
   Dim wbTarget As Excel.Workbook       'target workbook; tabs: Notes, Input, Summary, 1, 2, 4, 7
   Dim wbSource As Excel.Workbook       'source workbook; tabs: Notes, 1, 2, 4, 7, Misc
   Dim wsTarget As Excel.Worksheet      'worksheet where the data is to be pasted (eg. 1, 2, 4, 7)
   Dim wsSource As Excel.Worksheet      'worksheet from where the data is to copied (eg. 1, 2, 4, 7)
   Dim TrgName As String                'name of the target workbook tab
   Dim SrcName As String                'name of the source workbook tab
   Dim s As Integer                     'counter used for each tabs (eg. 1, 2, 4, 7)
   Dim period As String                 'qtr period
   Dim year As Integer                  'current year report
   Dim qtr As Integer                   'current qtr report
   Dim first As Long
   Dim last As Long
   Dim RowQ1 As Long, RowQ2 As Long, RowQ3 As Long, RowQ4 As Long
   Dim ColQ1 As Long, ColQ2 As Long, ColQ3 As Long, ColQ4 As Long

   'select the Qtr Period to report
   period = "Q4"
   year = 2013

   'set the following for use in range names
   'e.g.  for tab 1
   '   Q1 = Range("'1'!A1:CB200")
   '   Q2 = Range("'1'!A250:CB300")
   '   Q3 = Range("'1'!A350:CB400")
   '   Q4 = Range("'1'!A450:CB500")

   RowQ1 = 1
   RowQ2 = 250
   RowQ3 = 350
   RowQ4 = 450
   ColQ1 = 200
   ColQ2 = 300
   ColQ3 = 400
   ColQ4 = 500
   first = 1
   last = 80


   'set to the current active workbook (the source book)
   Set wbSource = ActiveWorkbook
   Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\temp\targetfile_" & year & period & ".xlsx")

   'set counter to each tab; as long as the source name is not equal to "Notes", the loop should continue ---- I'm just not sure how to handle the target workbook and each worksheet
   s = 1
   For Each wsSource In Worksheets
     If wsSource.Name <> "Notes" And period = "Q1" Then     'For Q1 Period
       SrcName = wsSource.Name
       Worksheets("Notes").Cells(counter, 1).Value = SrcName
       wsSource.Activate
       Application.CutCopyMode = False
       wsSource.Range(Cells(RowQ1, first), Cells(ColQ1, last)).Copy
       TrgName = SrcName
       wbTarget.Activate
       wsTarget.Name = TrgName
       wsTarget.Range(Cells(RowQ1, first)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
       Application.CutCopyMode = False
     ElseIf wsSource.Name <> "Notes" And period = "Q2" Then     'For Q2 Period
       SrcName = wsSource.Name
       Worksheets("Notes").Cells(counter, 1).Value = SrcName
       wsSource.Activate
       Application.CutCopyMode = False
       wsSource.Range(Cells(RowQ2, first), Cells(ColQ2, last)).Copy
       TrgName = SrcName
       wbTarget.Activate
       wsTarget.Name = TrgName
       wsTarget.Range(Cells(RowQ2, first)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
       Application.CutCopyMode = False
     ElseIf wsSource.Name <> "Notes" And period = "Q3" Then     'For Q3 Period
       SrcName = wsSource.Name
       Worksheets("Notes").Cells(counter, 1).Value = SrcName
       wsSource.Activate
       Application.CutCopyMode = False
       wsSource.Range(Cells(RowQ3, first), Cells(ColQ3, last)).Copy
       TrgName = SrcName
       wbTarget.Activate
       wsTarget.Name = TrgName
       wsTarget.Range(Cells(RowQ3, first)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
       Application.CutCopyMode = False
     ElseIf wsSource.Name <> "Notes" And period = "Q4" Then     'For Q4 Period
       SrcName = wsSource.Name
       Worksheets("Notes").Cells(counter, 1).Value = SrcName
       wsSource.Activate
       Application.CutCopyMode = False
       wsSource.Range(Cells(RowQ4, first), Cells(ColQ4, last)).Copy
       TrgName = SrcName
       wbTarget.Activate
       wsTarget.Name = TrgName
       wsTarget.Range(Cells(RowQ4, first)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
       Application.CutCopyMode = False
     s = s + 1
     End If

  Next wsSource

  'save the target book
  wbTarget.Save

  'close the workbook
  wbTarget.Close

  'activate the source book again
  wbSource.Activate

  'clear memory
  Set wbTarget = Nothing
  Set wbSource = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Is your code not working as needed, or are you getting errors when you run it ?  What exactly is the *problem* ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what problem you're running into. As for efficiency. You are running the same block of code four times. You can do something like this and make the code much easier to maintain.

```
Dim wbTarget As Excel.Workbook       'target workbook; tabs: Notes, Input, Summary, 1, 2, 4, 7
Dim wbSource As Excel.Workbook       'source workbook; tabs: Notes, 1, 2, 4, 7, Misc
Dim wsTarget As Excel.Worksheet      'worksheet where the data is to be pasted (eg. 1, 2, 4, 7)
Dim wsSource As Excel.Worksheet      'worksheet from where the data is to copied (eg. 1, 2, 4, 7)
Dim TrgName As String                'name of the target workbook tab
Dim SrcName As String                'name of the source workbook tab
Dim s As Integer                     'counter used for each tabs (eg. 1, 2, 4, 7)
Dim period As String                 'qtr period
Dim year As Integer                  'current year report
Dim qtr As Integer                   'current qtr report
Dim first As Long
Dim last As Long
Dim RowQ1 As Long, RowQ2 As Long, RowQ3 As Long, RowQ4 As Long
Dim ColQ1 As Long, ColQ2 As Long, ColQ3 As Long, ColQ4 As Long

Sub start()

   'select the Qtr Period to report
   period = "Q4"
   year = 2013

   'set the following for use in range names
   'e.g.  for tab 1
   '   Q1 = Range("'1'!A1:CB200")
   '   Q2 = Range("'1'!A250:CB300")
   '   Q3 = Range("'1'!A350:CB400")
   '   Q4 = Range("'1'!A450:CB500")

   RowQ1 = 1
   RowQ2 = 250
   RowQ3 = 350
   RowQ4 = 450
   ColQ1 = 200
   ColQ2 = 300
   ColQ3 = 400
   ColQ4 = 500
   first = 1
   last = 80


   'set to the current active workbook (the source book)
   Set wbSource = ActiveWorkbook
   Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\temp\targetfile_" & year & period & ".xlsx")

   'set counter to each tab; as long as the source name is not equal to "Notes", the loop should continue ---- I'm just not sure how to handle the target workbook and each worksheet
   s = 1
   For Each wsSource In Worksheets
     If wsSource.Name <> "Notes" And period = "Q1" Then     'For Q1 Period
        Call work(RowQ1, ColQ1, s)
     ElseIf wsSource.Name <> "Notes" And period = "Q2" Then     'For Q2 Period
        Call work(RowQ2, ColQ2, s)
     ElseIf wsSource.Name <> "Notes" And period = "Q3" Then     'For Q3 Period
        Call work(RowQ3, ColQ3, s)
     ElseIf wsSource.Name <> "Notes" And period = "Q4" Then     'For Q4 Period
        Call work(RowQ4, ColQ4, s)
     End If
     s = s + 1

  Next wsSource

  'save the target book
  wbTarget.Save

  'close the workbook
  wbTarget.Close

  'activate the source book again
  wbSource.Activate

  'clear memory
  Set wbTarget = Nothing
  Set wbSource = Nothing

End Sub

Sub work(rq As Integer, cq As Integer, s as integer)

       SrcName = wsSource.Name
       Worksheets("Notes").Cells(s, 1).Value = SrcName
       wsSource.Activate
       Application.CutCopyMode = False
       wsSource.Range(Cells(rq, first), Cells(cq, last)).Copy
       wbTarget.Activate
       wsTarget.Name = SrcName
       wsTarget.Range(Cells(rq, first)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
       Application.CutCopyMode = False


End Sub
```

This could probably be do even better, just an example.

Maybe you can explain your problem a little more?

Comment: I revised according to your code and got a Compile error: ByRef argument type mismatch.  I also corrected the following line:

Comment: Worksheets("Notes").Cells(counter, 1).Value = SrcName

Comment: instead of "counter", it should have been "s"

Comment: My bad, Missed that. In that case 's' will also need to be passed to the sub. However this was meant to be an example of how to simplify code. Does this solve your problem? I'm still unclear on what you're current code is doing wrong.

Comment: I think that's my problem.  The code as it stands even with the correction of the "s" is still not working and I'm not sure why either. I'm still getting that Compile Error.

Comment: My bad...now it's my turn... I resolved the Compile Error. I needed to maintain the data type (ie. Integer should have been Long.) I think you're right. Now I do need to pass on the "s" to the sub but how do I do that?  When I ran my program, it gave me a run time error '424' on the following line:

Comment: SrcName = wsSource.Name

Comment: I've edited my code to show how to pass the extra variable. Look at the Sub Work(...) line.

Comment: If you maintain the cq and rq as Integers, won't I still have a data mismatch, since RowQ4 and ColQ4 is Long?

Comment: Oh ya, I didn't see they were longs. My bad again.

Comment: so, instead of Sub work (rq As Long, cq As Long, s As Integer), it should be Sub work (rq As Long, cq As Long) and the next line should be Dim s As Integer?

Comment: nevermind, you changed the number of parameters in the "work"

Comment: Yes and no. You got `Sub work (rq As Long, cq As Long, s As Integer)` right but you won't need `dim s as integer`.

Comment: Okay, so I fixed the Sub work line but I'm still getting a run time error 424

Comment: Where is it breaking? Can you give me more info?

Comment: It's breaking at SrcName = wsSource.Name  This is in the Sub work section.